# Repeated bootstrap datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have a dynamic form that may have repeated datepickers elements. I am using bootstrap datepicker.

```
<div class="col-xs-11">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control be-form-control form-input" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
        <span class="input-group-addon calendar-icon" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This element can be repeated . My issue is that with bootstrap datepicker I have included script as,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

But if I have two such datepicker fields then one works and other does not because both now have same id . How can dynamic no of datepickers with unique ids can be added.

Comment: not sure how you are repeating it, but you can use class selector.

Comment: check this fiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/370/]

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee class selector did work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have several datePicker then you should use a class instead of an id (an id must be unique)

```
$('.classDatePicker').datepicker();
```